# Java Android stop getting recurring decimal number

Tags: java, android-studio, double, decimal

I'm doing a calculation on android studio (java) and the answer that I get back is like 4.654783632444251. I don't want the long answers. Preferably Two Decimal places would be ideal. Using Double.parseDouble

Answer (score 1):

You can round it to two decimal places:

```java
Math.round(myNumber * 100) / 100
```

Or you can format it using

```java
String.format("%.2f", myNumber)
```

The second method even prints the decimal places if they are 0.

Comment: The user enters the answer in a textfield and the answer is displayed as Textview would your answer work on this

Comment: Use `String.format`. It returns a String.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

Just call this method entering your value and 2 places.

Comment: I'll give a try